# Get attributes for class and instance in python

Tags: python, class, instance, metaclass, getattr

In python work next code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    field = 1

>>> MyClass.field
1

>>> MyClass().field
1
```

When I want return value for custom fields I use next code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
       if name.startswith('fake'):
           return name
       raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                            (type(self).__name__, name))

>>> MyClass().fake
fake
```

But:

```
>>> MyClass.fake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class MyClass has no attribute 'fake'
```

Ok, for classes I can use next code:

```
class MyClassMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
       if name.startswith('fake'):
           return name
       raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                            (type(self).__name__, name))

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassMeta

>>> MyClass.fake
fake
```

But:

```
>>> MyClass().fake
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'fake'
```

To resolve this problem I use next code:

```
class FakeAttrMixin():
   def __getattr__(self, name):
       if name.startswith('fake'):
           return name
       raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %
                            (type(self).__name__, name))

class MyClassMeta(type, FakeAttrMixin):
    pass

class MyClass(object, FakeAttrMixin):
    __metaclass__ = MyClassMeta

>>> MyClass.fake
fake

>>> MyClass().fake
fake
```

`MyClass.fake` will call `__getattr__` with `MyClass` and `fake` arguments.

`MyClass().fake` will call `__getattr__` with `MyClass` instance and `fake` arguments.

And it's ok if I implement `__getattr__` logic only on my mixin and don't use `self` argument.

Can I write custom value resolving by class and instance more beautiful and why `field` value resolving for `MyClass.field` and `MyClass().field` with `MyClass(object): field = 1` definition works different if compare with `__getattr__` method? Because when I want get `field` it at first searching in instance, then in class, but I can't understand why `__getattr__` works another way.

Similar questions: [__getattr__ on a class and not (or as well as) an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559120/getattr-on-a-class-and-not-or-as-well-as-an-instance) and [Difference between accessing an instance attribute and a class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304868/difference-between-accessing-an-instance-attribute-and-a-class-attribute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you have to support both arbitrary attribute lookup on the class as well as the instance, then your only option is to implement a `__getattr__` hook method on both the metaclass and the class, one each to support lookups on the class and the instance.

This is because special hook methods are *always* looked up on the type, so `type(obj).__getattr__`. Hence, for `MyClass.fake` the metaclass `__getattr__` is used. See [Special method lookup for new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup); I explained why this is in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14102566).

The short reason is that in your case, `MyClass.fake` would translate into `MyClass.__getattr__('fake')` and `__getattr__` is then an unbound method expecting *two* arguments (`self` and `name`), which would fail.