# __getattribute__ on instance and class

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I have a metaclass and and class that both use `__getattribute__` to intercept attribute calls. They look like this:

```
class B(type):    
    def __getattribute__ (self, name) :
        print(f'hello {self}')
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

class C(metaclass=B):
    MY_ATTR = 'hello attr'

    def __getattribute__ (self, name) :
        print(f'hello {self}')
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

This behaves as I intend:

```
C.MY_ATTR  
# hello <class 'C'>
# 'hello attr'

C().MY_ATTR
# hello <C object at 0x10bcbbda0>
# 'hello attr'
```

Now I want to take that duplicate code from `B` and `C` and let it be inherited. Lucky I called them `B` and `C` and left room for `A`. Here we go:

```
class A:
    def __getattribute__ (self, name) :
        print(f'hello {self}')
        return super().__getattribute__(name)

class B(type, A):
    pass

class C(A, metaclass=B):
    MY_ATTR = 'hello attr'
```

Unfortunately, this no longer behaves as before:

```
C.MY_ATTR  
# 'hello attr'

C().MY_ATTR
# hello <C object at 0x10bcbbda0>
# 'hello attr'
```

I assume the problem is something around a MetaClass not being able to inherit from a regular class but I'm unsure. I'm also open to any other implementations (maybe not requiring a metaclass) of getting the same behaviour - though I also still want calls like `C.MISSING` to raise a `AttributeError`.

There are similar questions to this (e.g. [Get attributes for class and instance in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387600/get-attributes-for-class-and-instance-in-python)) but they are slightly different and don't achieve what I'm trying to.

Thanks

Comment: OOC, what happens if you inherit from `A` first, e.g. `class B(A, type):`?

Comment: Yeah, I had tried this. C.MY_ATTR raises an exception. `hello <class 'C'> __getattribute__ TypeError: expected 1 arguments, got 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit more complicated than that - 
Metaclasses *do* accept ordinary classes as mixins - and any methods provided on these mixins will be available on the classes using those metaclasses as if they were classmethods (but they will be hidden from the instances - as attribute lookup on a n instance looks for the attribute on the class, but not on the metaclass).

However `__getattribute__` is a beast - it is hard to do it correctly even if no metaclass are involved (unlike `__getattr__`).

I did a bit of trial and error myself, and got that `type`'s `__getattribute__` does exist and is different from `object`'s - that is why you custom version is not called when you do the  `class M(type, A)` inheritance.  And also, if you swap the inheritance order, you see that  `super()` gets a corner case where it does not fill in the needed parameters to properly call `type.__getattribute__` .

I've tried to hardcode the call to `type.__getattribute__` with an `if` statement, and got in an attribute lookup loop, I could not figure out - the thing is non-trivial (but probably due to IPython introspection - see bellow).

Nonetheless, reusing code on the class and metaclass itself is something I had never seem.

If what you want to do in the `__getattribute__` body is nontrivial (as opposed to the example's `print`) I suggest you just factor the `__getattribute__`body  out to an ordinary function, and call it explicitly where you put the `print` on your examples - and just keep the three line `__getattribute__` on both the metaclass and class base:

```
def getattribute(instance_or_class, attr_name):
    # complex attr_name consuming body goes here.
    # even colateral effects on "self" can be applied
    # to the  "instance_or_class" object
    print(instance_or_class, attr_name)


class B(type):
    def __getattribute__ (cls, name):
        getattribute(cls, name)
        return super().__getattribute__(name)


class C(metaclass=B):
    MY_ATTR = 'hello attr'
    def __getattribute__ (self, name):
        getattribute(self, name)
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Now, one thing I see different from your first output - I actually get:

```
In [43]: C().MY_ATTR
<class '__main__.C'> __class__
<class '__main__.C'> __class__
<__main__.C object at 0x7fa420a314a8> MY_ATTR
Out[43]: 'hello attr'
```

That is, Python first looks up C `__class__` attribute -

Wait, on double checking, when doing it on the regular Python prompt, these calls do not occur - it is Ipython that triggers then, while at it's introspection magic things. It maybe the recursion loop I fell into was due to IPython's introspections - nonetheless, you will be avoiding a lot of unwanted magic letting the `__getattribute__` explicit in the metaclass and base classes, and factoring it out as above.

```
>>> C().MY_ATTR
<__main__.C object at 0x7f0d4d908898> MY_ATTR
'hello attr'
>>> C.MY_ATTR
<class '__main__.C'> MY_ATTR
'hello attr'
>>>
```

Comment: Great response, thank you. I actually did try separating out the logic into an external function but that caused its own set of errors. This was a while back now so I can't remember specifically. Though, I may have been using the REPL and was getting inspection errors - like you mentioned. I'll see if I have that code committed in git or if I can reproduce. Thanks again